# Why am I getting "access denied" using "wmic"?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, wmi

I have two machines, A and B, and a both with a local user called Bob that can RDP into both machines.

However, when I'm on machine A, that I open "cmd.exe", and then type `wmic /node:"machine-b" process call create "ipconfig"`, I'm getting "Access denied." Vice versa from B to A.

If Bob is a local admin on B, I am able to wmic from A. This is not preferable from a security standpoint.

What are my options to deal with this?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Edit:
The local passwords for Bob are the same on both machines, which are also connected to the same Domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is looking for what fixed the issue:

The problem was that Bob was in the "Remote Desktop Users" group, however the account also needs to be in the "Remote Management Users" group.

Answer (score 0):

This works when there are matching named user accounts on both machines where the password for both user accounts is the same. This is a function of pass-through NTLM authentication. One option for you would be to use different users accounts on each machine and pass the appropriate username/password in your commands. Another option would be to join these machines to the same Active Directory domain, which would require you to deploy an AD domain

Comment: Thanks your your reply joeqwerty, I forgot to mention that both the accounts have the same password and are joined to the same Domain. I've updated the original question. I'm also looking for answer that uses just the Bob account on both machines.

Comment: I've also just tested accessing Machine B from Machine A with wmic using a Domain User without success. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well sometimes WMIC can be tricky if you don't add it manually into each computer for security reasons.
First of all, I will disable the firewall for both machines and test (maybe it's a block of the firewall (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/84c78946-eb05-4068-877d-489153419d13/how-to-enable-the-wmi-entry-in-the-firewall-configuration-using-gpo-on-win7?forum=winserverGP)

A simpler solution would be to use the pstools option as part of the sisteminternals suite https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx

Full list of what you can do in here: http://www.programering.com/a/MzMyADMwATU.html

Also if you keep getting failures in that wmic you can also use the PowerShell savior of wmi 
Here's how to set it https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx
And more documentation here
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_wmi.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jose. The firewall rules are open on both Machines and wmic is working when the user is a local admin on the target machine.

Comment: then for sure should be permissions
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771551%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've just tried amending the wmi permissions, allowing Bob access to Root, as per that article and I'm still getting the Access Denied error.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably due to [remote uac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/951016/description-of-user-account-control-and-remote-restrictions-in-windows-vista) filtering your security token into a low integrity one, disable it and it should probably work.
notice this opens up many other options to remotely manage the other computer.

Comment: Hi Jonathon, thanks for your input. I've just checked the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` key, as per the technet article, and it's already set to 1 as the article suggests. For the sake of testing I also tried setting the value to 0 however I'm still getting Access Denied.

Comment: you have to restart the computer after changing,have you done that?